# getElementByID( i ) in for loop not working

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to target multiple elements with a specific ID inside of a for loop. Here's my code:

```
var insMax = document.getElementsByClassName('instagramimg');
    for (var i = 0 ; i < insMax.length; i++) {
      var insIMG = document.getElementById('instagramID'+i);
      insIMG.addEventListener('click' , function() {
        document.getElementById('instagramPopup'+i).classList.remove("hide");
      });
    }
```

Somehow this doesn't work and I get the error that it can't read `getElementById('instagramPopup'+i)` because it's null. This part `document.getElementById('instagramID'+i)` works just fine. When I run the same code, but with `document.getElementById('instagramPopup0).classList.remove("hide");` everything works fine. Why does this not work although it should be two times the exact same thing?

Answer (score 1):

Your variable `i` will have iterated to the end (taking the value `insMax.length`) by the time the click handler is executed. And so the value of `i` is not any more what you expected it to be at the time you evaluate `'instagramPopup'+i`.

Solve this by creating a separate `i` instance for each iteration: change `var i` to `let i`.

Comment: Thank you very much! Solved!